# Colab Pro and raspberry pi 4 not working, get disconnected

Tags: google-colaboratory, raspberry-pi4

With google Colab you can run a model for hours, to avoid using the desktop computer cause it uses too much power I'm trying to use Raspberry pi instead. Screen Blanking is disable, however the screen is switch off in order to not consume more power.

What happens? in 30-40 minutes running Colab Pro gets disconnected and stops the program. what is not working here? The same program is working perfectly in a desktop computer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if if will work, but my first hypotesis is to use this code in browser console:

```js
function CaptchaButton(){
    console.log("Captcha pushed");
    document.getElementsByTagName("colab-recaptcha-dialog")[0].close()
}

setInterval(CaptchaButton,600000);
```

In order to check the "I'm not a Robot" captcha.